# Why does findcontrol need unique id, when I have given it the row to scan

Tags: c#, findcontrol

## The code

```
    public partial class Table_Traversing : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
        Table table1 = new Table();

        Button button1 = new Button();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int adding_rows = 0; adding_rows < 4; adding_rows++)
               {
               TableRow table_row1 = new TableRow();
               TableCell table_cell1 = new TableCell();
               TableCell table_cell2 = new TableCell();
               Label The_text = new Label();
               CheckBox checkmate = new CheckBox();
               The_text.Text = "This is the text :-)";
               checkmate.ID = "checkmate";
               table_cell2.Controls.Add(checkmate);
               table_cell1.Controls.Add(The_text);
               table_row1.Controls.AddAt(0, table_cell1);
               table_row1.Controls.AddAt(1, table_cell2);
               table1.Rows.Add(table_row1);
               }
            button1.Text = "click me to export the value";
            form1.Controls.AddAt(0, table1);
            form1.Controls.AddAt(1, button1);
            button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);     
        }

        void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        CheckBox check_or_not = new CheckBox();
         for (int i = 0; i < table1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
             check_or_not = (CheckBox)table1.Rows[i].FindControl("checkmate");
             Response.Write(check_or_not.Checked.ToString());
             }       
         }
      }
```

### The error

> Multiple controls with the same ID 'checkmate' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Multiple controls with the same ID 'checkmate' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You added the checkbox to the cell, not the row:

```
table_cell2.Controls.Add(checkmate);
```

Hence - one row has multiple cells with id "checkmate":

E.g

```
<tr id="somerow">
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkmate"/></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkmate"/></td>
</tr>
```

So within the row "somerow", there are multiple checkboxes with id "checkmate".

Your code to add the checkboxes seemingly looks like you're only adding one though - so it must be something you've missed.

Try removing the FindControl code and see what actual HTML get's rendered.

Answer (score 2):

Just append the row number to the ID:

```
checkmate.ID = "checkmate" + adding_rows.ToString();
```

And of course, append it to your FindControl parameter as well:

```
check_or_not = (CheckBox)table1.Rows[i].FindControl("checkmate" + i.ToString());
```

Comment: thanks did that to solve this, but above user explained why the error so ... but urs helpful too thanku